# Variable binding through if statement not working correctly

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I wrote this code:

```
let x = 5;
let y = if x == 5 {
    10
} else {
    println!("shapoopoy");
};
```

When I compile with `cargo build`, I get the error:

```
error[E0308]: if and else have incompatible types
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
3 |       let y = if x == 5 {
  |  _____________-
4 | |         10
  | |         -- expected because of this
5 | |     } else {
6 | |         println!("shapoopoy");
  | |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected integer, found ()
7 | |     };
  | |_____- if and else have incompatible types
  |
  = note: expected type `{integer}`
             found type `()`
```

On a side note, if I plan on working on a project after learning Rust, should I stick with the stable releases? I'm not sure how to include Rust with the program I make if I do use an older version.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've done that a few times and was _very_ uncomfortable that it wasn't an error, so I'm glad to see this. `y` can't equal `println!()` unless its return value is an integer, after all.

Comment: This has *never* worked, as far as I can recall. Can you say when it did work?

Comment: I see. I assumed it would println!() only if y was not equal to 5

Comment: @JohnC can you provide an example of when that code compiled?

Comment: @Shepmaster Looking at my code, I _think_ I misremembered it for earlier versions of `match`.

Comment: Could you link to the docs where you got that snippet of code? I'd like to make sure that there's not a bug in the docs. Most of the examples in the docs are compiled to make sure they are valid, but you never know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your example code:

```
let x = 5;
let y = if x == 5 {
    10
} else {
    println!("shapoopoy");
};
```

What would the *type* of `y` be? The first branch resolves as some integral variable (like `u8` or `i32`), but the second branch resolves as the return type of `println!`, which is `()`. You can't store **both** these types in a single space, so the compiler complains.

Both branches need to resolve to the same type - and that's up to what you need to do. You could return nothing, and set the variable as a side-effect:

```
let x = 5;
let y;

if x == 5 {
    y = 10;
} else {
    println!("shapoopoy");
}
```

Or return a integer in both branches:

```
let x = 5;
let y = if x == 5 {
    10
} else {
    println!("shapoopoy");
    42
};
```

> I'm not sure how to include Rust with the program I make if I do use an older version.

Rust is a compiled language. If you distribute compiled binaries, then you don't need to "include" Rust at all. If you pick a stable version, then you can always pin to that version of Rust and compile with it.